# Função para renderizar componentes

Tags: javascript

Muitas são as vantagens de desenvolver utilizando a metodologia de componentes, mas aqui na empresa, algo que a equipe não consegue abrir mão é o jQuery, por diversos fatores.

Estou querendo criar um micro-framework que trabalhe diretamente no DOM, mas que me permita, também, trabalhar com componentes. Um intermédio entre Vue e jQuery.

Cada componente será um objeto com: `name`, `data`, `template` e `components`.

- `name` nome do componente que será registrado e como será chamado
- `data` dados e informações daquele componente
- `components` métodos que ele poderá ter
- `template` Template do componente

Exemplo de componente:

```
{
  name: 'componentePrincipal',

  template: `
    <h1>{{ titulo }}</h1>
    @outroComponente`,

  data: {
    titulo: 'Componente Bacana',
  },

  components: {
    outroComponente,
  },
}
```

E a função que usei para renderizar o componente principal foi:

```
render(component) {
  Object.keys(component.data).map(
    data => {
      component.template = component.template.replace(
        `{{ ${data} }}`,
        component.data[data]
      )
    }
  );

  Object.keys(component.components).map(
    ic => {
      component.template = component.template.replace(
        `@${ic}`,
        // aqui que tá o problema
        this.render(component.components[ic])
      )
    }
  );

  return component.template;
}
```

Com a ideia elaborada, tive um enorme problema de cara: não saber fazer com que um componente dentro de outro componente seja renderizado.

O erro que estou tendo ao renderizar o componente é:

> Cannot convert undefined or null to object

[Código no Gist](https://gist.github.com/danielbonifacio/c8af8ac672dfc2e1f1deb7bb951b3da6)